# Breakpoint no visual studio não carrega no momento do debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Tenho uma solução com 3 projetos, sendo uns deles Ex.utils e Ex.Api. Onde a .dll do projeto utils é referenciado no Ex.Api em 'References'. Ambos compilados na mesma versão do .NET.

Ao rodar  o debug, o breakpoint, após inúmeras pesquisas, mantém-se como se tivesse indisponível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Começou do nada? É só nesse bloco de código?

Comment: Já tentou dar um `clean` e um `rebuild` na `solution`?

Comment: Já fiz o que o @MarcoGiovanni citou, já comparei a versão do .NET dos projetos, ambos iguais.

Comment: @GabrielColetta acontece isso em qualquer lugar que eu coloque o breakpoint para debug.

Comment: começou do nada? Ou você acabou de instalar a IDE?

Comment: Dentro das condições do break point, você tem a configuração do local. Clique em "Habilitar o fonte de um local diferente do original" e veja se da certo

Comment: Acabei de baixar, instalei as dependências e plugins e associei ao meu banco de dados. O projeto roda 'ok', só não estou conseguindo debugar.

Comment: De uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738954/6163123) para ver se ajuda

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni cheguei a checar essa alternativa também.

Comment: @DiegoSantos poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Respondendo abaixo com print, vê se resolve...

Comment: Provavelmente está sendo compilado em modo Release, altere para Debug. [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPHF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPHF.png)

Comment: O tópico é antigo, mas aconteceu comigo, então, pode ser que outras pessoas passem por isso. Verifique se não alterou as configurações da solução para RELEASE no lugar de DEBUG.. estava distraída e não vi, fiquei uns minutos batendo a cabeça.. =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já tentou checar se o projeto que esta debugando esta marcado como principal?
Quando eu uso mais de um projeto as vezes acontece comigo.
Se eu tiver dois projetos web na mesma solution e for debugar um e o outro estiver marcado como "as startup project" ele debuga apenas o que estiver marcado.

Espero que seja esse o seu caso! abs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Também passei por isto, é ncessário que você clique nas propriedades do projeto,
na aba Build, clique em advanced, e na opção "Debbuging Information", deixa como Full.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

**Tente desta forma:**

Clique com botão direito no break point, depois, clique em *"Conditions"*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique no link logo após *"Location:"*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Habilite o checkbox "Allow the source code to be different from the original".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez resolva...

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Mas valeu a tentativa! :)

Answer (score 0):

sei que estou sendo atrasado, mas, espero ajudar outrem que porventura necessite.
eu também passei por isso, hoje. a minha solução foi desabilitar a opção apenas o meu código.
para tal, precisarás ir até em [depurador] -> [opções] -> [Geral] -> [habilitar apenas meu código].